# Using multiple \multicolumn commands in a table to achieve column headers

Tags: tables

I'm trying to code column headers in LaTeX so that each header spans two columns; however, the following code isn't working:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Assets} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
Cash & \$13,152 & Short position (200 shares owed) & \$13,152 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

`Assets` should span the first two columns, and `Liabilities and Equities` should span the second pair. When I compile this, I get this error:

```
Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.221 ...lticolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: This is now correct! Please see my comment. I can't add an answer for a while because I'm new, but maybe someone else could and I'll up vote it.

Comment: I was missing the ampersand between the multicolumn statements. Adding it corrected the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you already noticed the missing `&` between the two `\multicolumn` statements. One more thing: you may want to change the trimming option on the second `\cmidrule` statement from `(r)` to `(l)`, in order to get a bit more of a horizontal separation between the two lines. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing `&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Assets} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Liabilities and Equities} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
Cash & \$13,152 & Short position (200 shares owed) & \$13,152 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `&` between `\cmidrule` will cause an error!

Comment: Yes it does; -1 if I could.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have corrected that.  It had compiled for me, but then I had commented that line out while trying to determine the problem. When I noticed that line being commented I was able to get it to compile for me, but forgot that I had also removed the `&`.